# netsh in command line to change adaptor settings?

Tags: dns, cmd.exe, netsh, ipconfig

I have been playing around with `netsh` to make some changes to the network adpater on a machine called "Local Area Connection"
I would like to change the IP, SUBNET, GATEWAY & DNS

IP: `192.168.1.10`

SUBNET: `255.255.255.0`

GATEWAY: `10.10.11.12`

DNS: `8.8.8.8`

I thought the following command would work however I am having no luck, can anyone see where I am going wrong?

```
netsh interface ip set address "Local Area Connection" static 192.168.1.10 255.255.255.0 10.10.11.12

netsh interface ip set dns "Local Area Connection" static 8.8.8.8
```

I have looked over the netsh guide however I just seem to be getting more confused!

Comment: Why the gateway is way different than the IP?

Comment: These are just example settings, not the final ones I will be using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the `name` alias. You need to specify what version of IP you want to make the changes (IPv4 or IPv6).

The correct commands are:

> `netsh interface ipv4 set address name="Local Area Connection" static 192.168.1.10 255.255.255.0 10.10.11.12`
>
> `netsh interface ipv4 set dns name="Local Area Connection" static 8.8.8.8`

Comment: Hello it worked!

However I have no idea why this works:

> ` netsh interface ipv4 set address name="Local Area Connection" static 192.168.1.10 255.255.255.0 10.10.11.12 1`

and this doesn't work:

> ` netsh interface ipv4 set address name="Local Area Connection" static %FIRSTIP% %SUBNETIP% %GATEWAY% 1`